# Tags of the week! April 22-28, 2019: Essay & Marketing — RESULTS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

## WEEK: April 22-28, 2019
TAGS: [essay](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay) and [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing)

---

## Results

**And our winner is... it's a tie.**

Congrats.  Cyndi and April each posted 1 question about [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing).  It was a slow week with only two promo-eligible questions.

But retagging efforts won the day.  [essay](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay) now has 150 questions and [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) has gone all the way up to 154.  Woo hoo!  That's an increase of 23 questions either added or correctly re-tagged.

---

At the start of this week [essay](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay) had 140 questions and [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) had 141. Let see how high we can get them by week's end.

---

As a followup to our [fantastic tag contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/announcing-our-contest-results?cb=1), and to suggestions that we [continue the fun](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/suggestion-continue-question-pushes/1955) in a more informal way, here is Writing.SE's fourth:

## TAGS OF THE WEEK PROMO

### Rules:

- The contest runs for one week, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or both of the tags of the week.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the week, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use both tags in the same question.

---

**Notes:**

- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this week's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal is to increase questions on tags that have not yet reached the magic 200 questions.  My personal focus is tags that are in the top 40 tags but under 200 questions.
- Others may take over other weeks and they may have different goals.
- Each week we'll have two tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

This contest is linked from [this Meta.SE post about topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327017/162102).  (Please update it for new challenges.)

Comment: Slow week!  Anyone want to contribute a question?  Now's the time.  And who would like to do next week's promo?

Comment: Hey folks it's almost time to start a new week.  Any volunteers?  Please note I have created a list of the tags in question to make it easier to track.  https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1987/32946

Comment: yay retaggers, FTW!

Answer (score 3):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

- April [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) - [How to "market" my podcast?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44742/how-to-market-my-podcast)
- Cyn [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) - [Comics marketing: focus on issues or collections?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44757/comics-marketing-focus-on-issues-or-collections)